# need help about settimeout() jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors, selector

Here is my html. I want to show specific paragraph when I'll select different option. also want to show a loader before showing each paragraph. suppose when I'll select Algeria from the select it should be show first loader, after few second the loader should hide and show the specific paragraph which contain the id="algeria".

```
<select id="oh-select">
    <option value="algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="brazil">Brazil</option>
    <option value="brunei">Brunei</option>
    <option value="cameroon">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="canada">Canada</option>
</select>

<div id="oi-loader"> Loading</div>

<p class="nothing" id="algeria">Algeria</p>
<p class="nothing" id="australia">Australia</p>
<p class="nothing" id="brazil">Brazil</p>
<p class="nothing" id="brunei">Brunei</p>
<p class="nothing" id="cameroon">Cameroon</p>
<p class="nothing" id="canada">Canada</p>
```

The problem is if want to show paragraph using setTimeout() after few second on change it's not working.but without setTimeout() it's working partially. Here is jquery what I wrote:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#oi-loader").hide();
    $('.nothing').hide();

    $('#oh-select').change(function() {
        $('.nothing').hide();
        $("#oi-loader").show();

        setTimeout(function() {
                $("#oi-loader").hide();
            }, 3000);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
            }, 4000);

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `$(this).val()` to a variable to avoid the change of its value by changing its functional context.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#oi-loader").hide();
    $('.nothing').hide();

    $('#oh-select').change(function() {

        // assigning this to a variable
        var a = $(this).val() 

        $('.nothing').hide();
        $("#oi-loader").show();

        setTimeout(function() {
                $("#oi-loader").hide();
            }, 3000);

        setTimeout(function() {

        // using variable
                $("#" + a).show();
            }, 4000);

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to use setTimeout() function twice, you can write this code like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                
            $("#oi-loader").hide();
            $('.nothing').hide();

            $('#oh-select').change(function() {                     
                var curEle = $(this).val();
                $("#oi-loader").show();
                $('.nothing').hide();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#" + curEle).show();
                    $("#oi-loader").hide();
                }, 4000);                
            });
        });
```